# Substrate Offchain Worker - failed to fetch sample price

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, offchain-worker

I am trying to use Substrate Offchain Worker. I implemented as mentioned here https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/frame/examples/offchain-worker.

I am using same sample

```
 let deadline = sp_io::offchain::timestamp().add(Duration::from_millis(2_000));
        let request =
            http::Request::get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD");
        let pending = request.deadline(deadline).send().map_err(|_| http::Error::IoError)?;
        let response = pending.try_wait(deadline).map_err(|_| http::Error::DeadlineReached)??;
        if response.code != 200 {
            log::warn!("Unexpected status code: {}", response.code);
            return Err(http::Error::Unknown)
        }
```

When I start my local parachain node with `--offchain-worker always`, I get below error after each block production:

`Evicting failed runtime instance error=Runtime panicked: Accessing a forbidden API: http_request_start. No: HTTP capability.`

This URL `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD` is working fine in my browser.

Can somebody please guide me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow http requests.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/283d3cc5676417a29783786a41a01680d123f7bb/substrate/client/offchain/src/lib.rs#L112